# googlechecks.xml does not work in checkstyle5.6.1

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I found googlechecks.xml from https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml . Imported it to checkstyle and have been trying to use this in checkstyle 5.6.1(Eclipse juno 4.2,JRE1.6). Problem occurs at **FileExtension property**. 
I also want to add new rules in the xml file. Could anyone please let me know how to overcome this problem? That would be a great help and reapply appreciable.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: Hi vijay.. I want to run google_checks.xml in checkstyle 5.6.1. and want to add new rules to that. But It shows errors. So can I get google_checks.xml for 5.6.1 version by any chance..? Please let me know if you are aware.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use so ancient checkstyle version ([current](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html) is 7.1, last jdk7 based one is 6.19) and xml file from the latest master version?

Upgrade your checkstyle to at least 6.19 before using that file.

Or you can try to use older google checks, e.g. from the:

- 6.1.1 release: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/c17bf06af9334ea1f6096868e591e6ee62774540/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml
- 5.8 release (when it first appeared): https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/8e4c7f743e5eebb38d039d15d8718d7b25587976/google_checks.xml

Comment: My project should work only under JDK6.. It's an old project. I cannot change it.. So just wondering if I can get google_checks.xml for 5.6.1 version by any chance..? Please let me know if you are aware.

Comment: You can have different JDK for compilation and for running the checks.

Comment: More over 6.1.1 is the last release in JDK6 so you can still use it, maybe it will work better.

Comment: Yay.. I could use the above xml file for checkstyle5.8. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. And Any idea on how to add a rule in that? Is there any words/syntax that need to be followed? I will check but wondering if you can help me on that either. :)

Comment: @Likhita You would need to read checkstyle website for that. Also consider marking this answer as accepted (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and potentially upvote it if it helped http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow